# On the Diophantine equation $a^3 + b^3 = c^3 + d^3$

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

Let $a, b, c$ and $d$ be positive integers. What are the conditions that $a, b, c$ and $d$ should satisfy for the equality $$a^3 + b^3 = c^3 + d^3$$ to hold? In particular, can $a, b, c$ and $d$ be all perfect squares?

Comment: $a=c=n^2, b=d=m^2$ is always a solution. So yes, they can all be perfect squares.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_number

Comment: @NickS, okay, but I think solutions with $a=c$ and $b=d$ can be regarded as "trivial".

Comment: All squares are unlikely as equal sums of 6th powers [are believed](http://euler.free.fr/details.htm) to have at least 6 summands in total.

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev, thanks for your comments. Let me check out your reference...

Comment: Numbers that are sums of two cubes in more than one way are tabulated & discussed at https://oeis.org/A001235

Comment: A complete parametric solution in positive integers of $a^3+b^3=c^3+d^3$ is known: see [Choudhry 1998](https://www.jstor.org/stable/44238229) Theorem 2.

Answer (score 3):

You ask about the set of solutions for which $a,b,c,d$ are all perfect squares. This corresponds (with an abuse of notation) to solutions to the equation
$$a^6 + b^6 = c^6 + d^6.$$
This defines a surface of general type. The Bombieri-Lang conjecture predicts that the solutions to the equation are not Zariski dense. Therefore the solutions to the original equation which are all perfect squares should be very rare indeed.